# Can I deploy a Cubicweb application without the source code?

Tags: python

Can I deploy a Cubicweb Python application without the source code?

So far I've deployed my Cubicweb application including the Python source code. I'll like to deploy the object executable code only.

I don't want to convert it to exe because I need it to run in Linux also.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the usual methods for creating executables from Python packages apply equally well to CubicWeb applications.

If your goal is to distribute a single executable file you can use appimagetool with python-appimage as basis. This solution is described here: https://python-appimage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#repackaging-the-appimage

It is still possible to extract the appimage and to inspect the code though.

Alternatively, you can use PyInstaller. It compiles python files to `.pyc` files before bundling them into an executable. But `.pyc` files can be easily de-compiled and inspected. Also note that when running the executable all files are extracted to /tmp/.

If you want to make it harder to inspect/de-compile your code, you can compile it with Cython first, and then use PyInstaller or appimagetool to create an executable for example.

You could also try to obfuscate your code but I don't know any good program to obfuscate whole python packages.